# Error when using getter/setter methods on Sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, class, static, setter, getter

I'm trying to make a class that extends the Sprite, have some private properties attached to it and be able to read and write those properties using getters and setters. 
Simple... but the compiler throw this error "Access of possibly undefined property speed through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite."
It works if I set my class to extend the MovieClip object.
Could someone explain me the logic behind this? why I can't use getter and setters with a Sprite?

Here is a sample code:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Vehicle extends Sprite{

        private var _speed:uint = 3;


        public function get speed():uint {
            return _speed;
        }

        public function set speed(value:uint):void {
            _speed = value;
        }


        public function Vehicle() {
            super();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you typing your vehicle instance as type Sprite or type Vehicle? if the former, you will need to cast it as Vehicle before you get/set your prop.

Comment: You can use get/set with a Sprite, there must be a problem elsewhere. Please post the code where you instantiate a Vehicle, and where you use the accessors.

Comment: I was doing this way:
var vehicle:Sprite = new Vehicle();
addChild(vehicle);

Comment: Also keep in mind that in some cases it may be good practice to type it as a Sprite and access its unique properties by casting. Ex. (vehicle as Vehicle).speed. That way you can use the same variable, but split off logic in different implementations for similar types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the instance of the Vehicle as such, since Sprites are not dynamic as Movieclips.

So, doing this, does not work:

```
var vehicle:Sprite = new Vehicle;
vehicle.speed = 5;
```

This should work:

```
var vehicle:Vehicle= new Vehicle;
vehicle.speed = 5;

var vehicle:Sprite = new Vehicle;
Vehicle(vehicle).speed = 5; //We cast the vehicle instance to Vehicle type.
```

Also, we can cast using the `as` operator:

```
var vehicle:Sprite = new Vehicle;
(vehicle as Vehicle).speed = 5; //We cast the vehicle instance to Vehicle type.
```

Comment: Don't forget to call the constructor function: new Vehicle();

Comment: @Mark Knol: I am calling the constructor, perhaps you are confused with the second case, were i'm casting the vehicle instance to Vehicle...

Comment: @golia, Mark may have been misled by your choice to not use the parentheses. While it *works* to omit them when there are no parameters, it makes Adobe's recommended code standards angry, and some people who aren't aware they can be omitted confused.

Comment: @sam you are right, did not know about that syntax. It looks a bit confusing to me, like you don't call the constructor function. Thanks.